# Toggle Different Classes Sequentially

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, toggle

Well i am trying to create a button that you can click more then 2 times..

This seems to work but only changes two classes.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.box1').toggleClass('box4, box2, box3');
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 60% 20%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 60% 80%, 0% 80%);
}

.box4 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}

#buttox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 46%;
  right: 46%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div id="buttox"><button id="button" class="butt1">Run Effect</button></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

well I also tried without the commas.
I've searched everywhere and cannot find away to **toggle a button's class** more then 2 times with jQuery

Comment: `toggleClass` adds all the classes the element currently doesn't have, and removes all it currently does have. So `$('.box1').toggleClass('box4 box2 box3')` would add all those classes in one go. You can't do this with just one toggleClass call. You need to check what class the element has first, and then remove that class, and add the "next one."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .toggleClass() to step trough multiple classNames in a simple way, instead of classes, use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

- Use an array of the desired shape names
- Use [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to store the initial shape
- Use a *current index* variable, and increment it on click
- Use Modulo (Reminder) operator `%` to reset the index to 0 when necessary
- Use `.attr("data-shape", idx)` to change the data attribute value.
- DRY, don't repeat your styles that are not necessary

```js
const $shape = $("#shape");
const shapes = ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4"];
let tot = shapes.length;
let idx = 0;

const changeShape = () => {
  idx += 1;   // Increment current index
  idx %= tot; // Loopback to 0 when matches length
  $shape.attr("data-shape", shapes[idx]); // apply to data attribute
};

$("#button").on("click", changeShape);
```

```css
#shape {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

[data-shape="box1"] {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

[data-shape="box2"] {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
}

[data-shape="box3"] {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 60% 20%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 60% 80%, 0% 80%);
}

[data-shape="box4"] {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}

#buttox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 46%;
  right: 46%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape" data-shape="box1"></div>
<div id="buttox">
  <button id="button" class="butt1">Run Effect</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you really want to use classes you first need to remove the current class (index), increment the index and apply the new class:

```js
const $shape = $("#shape");
const shapes = ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4"];
let tot = shapes.length;
let idx = 0;

const changeShape = () => {
  $shape.removeClass(shapes[idx]); 
  idx += 1;
  idx %= tot;
  $shape.addClass(shapes[idx]); 
};

$("#button").on("click", changeShape);
```

```css
#shape {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.box2 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
}

.box3 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 60% 20%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 60% 80%, 0% 80%);
}

.box4 {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}

#buttox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 46%;
  right: 46%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape" class="box1"></div>
<div id="buttox">
  <button id="button" class="butt1">Run Effect</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @tacoshy ? I *did* used the more verbose and developer friendly `idx += 1;`. OP uses jQuery. querySelectorAll is not necessary (also, there's nothing to "querySelectorAll" in the above code.). Now we might argue that jQuery is not necessary but that's not in the scope of the question. The variables are named perfectly fine.

Comment: @tacoshy I think you missed that there's nothing to querySelectorAll. There's only **one** element `#shape` which changes `clip-path` via CSS :) and therefore I used the jQuery equivalent `$("#shape")` "quasi-equivalent" in vanilla JS to `querySelector("#shape")`. All your comments so far are misleading I'm afraid :\

Comment: my bad - I still would look for a way to simplify the process which is to broad for an answer and off-topic

Comment: how about just using the index `1` - `4` instead of `box1` to `box4`? Then you won't need the shapes array.

Comment: @tacoshy that's a viable solution, but *if* you have a library/list of all the shapes defined more verbosely like: `"arrow"` `"circle"` `"pentagon"` etc, not only you can be more explicit in the shape you're applying but also you can easily create subsets of the desired shapes and the order you're applying them. Otherwise, if it's just a simple task of looping trough N shapes, simply changing the index would be fit. In such case  I would than use `box0` so that I don't have to account for `index + 1`.

Comment: ya that works good for the clip-path..... but im looking to change the Div completly

Comment: @Timbukto I'm not sure what has *"but im looking to change the Div completly"* to do with your actual question? You never stated that you need to change DIVs or similar.

Comment: "*im looking to change the Div completly*"[sic] - you might like to ask a new question that actually asks the question that you want an answer for then.